# Keep "Interesting Tags" at the top of the page

Tags: feature-request

It would be nice if there was a way to keep the "interesting tags" section at the top of the page all the time. It's at the top when I go to SO, but if I click on one, its half way down the page to find it again (under ads & related tags).

Is there a way to pin this to the top?

**EDIT**

This is a bit evil, but for firefox users I've managed a solution that makes me happy. If you get the "Stylish" addon (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) you can then apply some styles to stackoverflow. I did the following:

```
#sidebar {
   position: relative;
   top: 70px;
   overflow: visible !important;
}
#interestingTags { 
   float: right;
   border: 1px brown solid !important;
   padding: 5px !important;
   display: block !important;
   position: absolute;
   top: -60px;
}
```

And I have my interesting tags at the top of the sidebar all the time :) At least on the pages where interesting tags appear :-)

Comment: A common request (I think) is to show only questions with tags that I'm interested in. I don't want to ignore something just because it happens to include something I'm not interested in, but if none of the tags interest me, I'm happy to hide it. Or else I go to http://ask.sqlservercentral.com instead.